# Rspec error: ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise

I have been surfing google and this site a ton but cannot get a solution for this error that works.  If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

All the controller tests are failing with roughly the same message.

[image]

It looks to me like all the data it needs is there, yet it is still failing.  For this test to work all it needs is the post id in the route, no sign in or anything like that.

I am confident I could get the rest working if I understood what was leading to this error.  Here is one example (the one that create the error above)

```
describe "GET #show" do
 it "assigns the requested post as @post" do
   post = FactoryGirl.create(:post)
   get :show, params: {id: post.to_param}, session: valid_session
   expect(assigns(:post)).to eq(post)
 end
end
```

There is a route that lines up to the show action in the posts controller...

[image]

..so I am a little unsure why this test (and all the tests for the controller) is failing.

I have looked at the the questions on here since about 2013 that dealt with this and they did not solve it for me. I just cannot get rspec to find this route so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried this one: `get :show, id: post.to_param, session: valid_session` ? And have you specified `type: :controller` ? like this: `RSpec.describe PostsController, type: :controller`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put the parameters under key `params`.

```
describe "GET #show" do
  it "assigns the requested post as @post" do
    post = FactoryGirl.create(:post)
    get :show, { id: post.to_param }, session: valid_session
    expect(assigns(:post)).to eq(post)
  end
end
```